# chart.js onAnimationProgress progress percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I want to change the fillColor as the animation occurs. In a way that makes it go from one color to the other, like blue->green.

I've been testing methods and so far I've been able to make the color change, but it's transition is not smooth.

The method currently involves 2 functions:

```
onAnimationProgress: function(){},

// Function - Will fire on animation completion.
onAnimationComplete: function(){}
```

but while using the onAnimationProgress, I can't see a way to see the progress of the animation, like how far along the progress is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `onAnimationProgress` has 2 parameters `easeDecimal` and `stepDecimal` that you can use

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    onAnimationProgress: function (easeDecimal, stepDecimal) {
        // stepDecimal proceeds uniformly from 0 to 1
        // easeDecimal proceeds depending on the easing function from 0 to 1
        console.log(stepDecimal)
    }
});
```

---

For instance, to change the `fillColor` - here I just adjust the transparency

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    animationSteps: 200,
    onAnimationProgress: function (easeDecimal, stepDecimal) {
        this.datasets[0].fillColor = "rgba(120,120,120," + stepDecimal + ")";
    }
});
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Now it's only a matter of changing the fillColor.